# How to create a "dummy" batch/simple program that opens and hold fie in ram

Tags: preloader

Ok so the title sounds a little intimidating and impossible, however this is what I want to do.

Basically I am creating a game preloader (a program that pre-loads some game files into the RAM so that when the game has to access the files they are already in the RAM)

I know the names of the files and the file paths for the files I would like to "pre-load".

I also noticed that when right clicking on the file (its a map) and open it with the game, it loads the map into the RAM before executing the game (I know this because before game and map opened, I had 2.52GB of ram used, when I opened the map with the game it spiked to 2.95 and just normal launching the game it used 2.8)

is there a way to essentially open all those files with the game, without opening the game a ton of times? I know my question was poorly worded but can someone at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way would be to use a ram drive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software

> RAM drive software allows part of a computer's RAM (memory) to be seen
>   as if it were a disk drive, with volume name and, if supported by the
>   operating system, drive letter. A RAM drive has very much faster read
>   and write access than a hard drive with rotating platters, and is
>   volatile, being destroyed with its contents when a computer is shut
>   down or crashes[1]—volatility is an advantage if security requires
>   sensitive data not to be stored permanently, and to prevent
>   accumulation of obsolete temporary data, but disadvantageous where a
>   drive is used for faster processing of needed data. Data can be copied
>   between conventional mass storage and a RAM drive to preserve it on
>   power-down and load it on start-up.

If you install your game into a ram drive it starts off already in ram and can be accessed faster then from a harddrive. Of course, you'll have to re-install the game to the ram disk every time you restart your computer. Some ram disk software will save the contents to disk for you however.

However you'll probably find if you are using a modern operating system that it caches the file in ram anyway (if you've plenty to spare) the second and further time it's accessed anyway so you might not see that much difference overall, after the first time access anyway.

Comment: Hi, I am looking to create a mod for the game, something that can be simply created by running an .exe, also the game would need to be modified to access the new files in a different directory. Since my idea seems impossible, is there a way to have cache stored in the ram be saved AFTER a program is closed or is that hard coded into windows?

Comment: You'd not have to modify the game. Just install it to the drive letter the ram disk provides, it's just like an ordinary drive. I don't understand your second point. Cache is managed for you by the operating system, you don't (generally) decide what is cached.